# How to connect to a VNC server running in a Linux Docker container?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, docker, vnc

How do you connect to a VNC server running inside a Docker container, from Linux?

I built and ran a Docker container based on [this configuration](https://github.com/sekka1/Dockerfile-Ubuntu-Gnome), which creates a full Gnome desktop. It built and ran without errors, and I can shell into it. However, I'm unable to connect to it from my host Linux environment.

VNC is exposed on port 5901, and `ifconfig` suggests the container is using IP 172.17.0.1. However, connecting using these paths with Remmina fails with the error "Couldn't convert  to host address":

```
vnc://172.17.0.1:5901
vnc://127.0.0.1:5901
vnc://localhost:5901
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is Remmina, which is just a terrible VNC client.

I tried `xtightvncviewer localhost:5901` and that connected immediately.